# Segmentation of a PointCloud to find a specific object (a cup) pcl

Tags: kinect, pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

In my task i need to detect the pose of an object (a cup in my case) because i have to grasp the cup with a robot.

I'm trying to catching the point cloud of the scene with ROS and a kinect.
I thought to segment my point cloud that represent the scene, because i want to keep only the point of the cup.
I have implemented a code in ROS that has a subscriber to detect the sensor_msgs/PointCloud2, then i transform the PointCloud2 in a pcl::PointXYZ.

And this is the code to the segmentation part:

```
pcl::ModelCoefficients::Ptr coefficients (new pcl::ModelCoefficients);
pcl::PointIndices::Ptr inliers (new pcl::PointIndices);
// Create the segmentation object
pcl::SACSegmentation<pcl::PointXYZ> seg;
// Optional
seg.setOptimizeCoefficients (true);
// Mandatory
seg.setModelType (pcl::SACMODEL_CYLINDER);
seg.setMethodType (pcl::SAC_RANSAC);
seg.setDistanceThreshold (0.01);
seg.setInputCloud (cloud);
seg.segment (*inliers, *coefficients);
```

it seems to work with a SACMODEL_PLANE, but with SACMODEL_CYLINDER this is the error that appears:

```
[pcl::SACSegmentation::initSACModel] No valid model given!
[pcl::SACSegmentation::segment] Error initializing the SAC model!
Could not estimate a planar model for the given dataset.
```

I found the various model here http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.7.0/group__sample__consensus.html

Help me please!

P.S. And tell me if i'm trying to do the correct things for my task...

Tank You!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173143/segmentation-of-a-pointcloud-to-find-a-specific-object-(a-cup)-pcl/) by [lukeb88](https://answers.ros.org/users/18311/lukeb88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2014-06-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest to follow this tutorial http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/cylinder_segmentation.php#cylinder-segmentation.
They use pcl::SACSegmentationFromNormals instead of pcl::SACSegmentation.
For me it works!

---

Originally posted by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) with karma: 620 on 2014-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know this is an old thread but just to clarify, this error happens because they never actually implemented a cylinder model in this module. You can check the code in here http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.0.1/sac__segmentation_8hpp_source.html in line #134 you can find the handler for different models and cylinder as well as others aren't defined and go to the default which throws your error.

All the unsuported models are:

SACMODEL_CIRCLE3D,
SACMODEL_CYLINDER,
SACMODEL_CONE,
SACMODEL_TORUS
SACMODEL_PARALLEL_LINES,
SACMODEL_NORMAL_PLANE,
SACMODEL_NORMAL_SPHERE,
SACMODEL_REGISTRATION,
SACMODEL_REGISTRATION_2D
SACMODEL_NORMAL_PARALLEL_PLANE
SACMODEL_STICK

---

Originally posted by [sosx](https://answers.ros.org/users/27944/sosx/) with karma: 11 on 2016-09-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DangTran](https://answers.ros.org/users/53085/dangtran/) on 2021-03-26**:
Update link: https://pointclouds.org/documentation/sac__segmentation_8hpp_source.html